# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')

Tags: wallets, error, beacon

I'm building a Bubble.io plugin to connect to Tezos Blockchain. I'm using @taquito/beacon-wallet to connect, but to use libs in Bubble you need to use webpack, the lib is working fine by console.logging, but when i call a function goes to this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
```

Before, my problem was the buffer, and i solved by adding it to webpack.config.js, like this:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      stream: false,
      buffer: require.resolve('buffer/'),
    }
```

I tried the same solution to call method, but won't worked

Comment: Can you provide some additional information about your error? Eg. where in the code it is thrown? This looks a lot like a webpack / compile error where something doesn't get polyfilled right or isn't accessible how it should be.

Comment: did you find a solution? facing the same issue

Comment: yes @nxmohamad, you need to user browserify.
Like this:   resolve: {
    fallback: {
      stream: false,
      buffer: require.resolve('buffer/'),
      stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify')
    }